# Shell Regular Expression Square Brackets Multiple Occurrences

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm writing a shell script that uses sed for returning contents within square brackets

```
sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g'
```

the problem is it only returns one occurrence even if there are multiple occurrences.
I want it so that it return all occurrences, what would I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

There will only ever be one occurrence because other square brackets will be matched by the `.*`s you surrounded your pattern with.

Instead, rewrite it to only match the section you you want, e.g. by replacing `.*` with `[^[]*`:

```
sed -n 's/[^[]*\[\([^]]*\)\][^[]*/\1 /gp'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`

```
awk -F"[][]" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with `sed` (for the moment), but I hope my `grep` solution will suit you:

```
grep -oE '\[[^]]*\]'
```

- `-o` is to get the exact matches
- `-E` is to use the regular expressions
- The regular expression gets everything which is between brackets, except closing brackets (for instance `[foo] bar [baz] foo` will return `[foo] [bar]`, and not `[foo] bar [baz]`)

Comment: Giving `-1` 5 seconds after post is posted is not fear, and the user who did should tell why. So I did gave `+1` even if its not the correct answer, since `[]` is not removed.

Comment: I guess this is because we did not answered using `sed`... ?

Comment: Maybe, but I do not see any requirement for `sed`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^[]*\[\([^]]*\)\][^[]*/\1/g' file
```

The problem you had was using `.*` which is greedy and bypassed all but the last occurrence of `[..]`

Comment: User who is giving `-1` to all post in this thread without telling should be banned, I do hope moderators read this.